# Auto click certain Javascript even on certain URL from same website

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, javascript-objects

I have the website `http://example.com/`, which basically has three Javascript events. Clicking each of the options will change the URL accordingly.

For example, when you click on "Option1", the URL changes to `http://example.com/#Option1`; when you click on "Option2", the URL changes to `http://example.com/#Option1`; etc.
These three sections will be accessed by the USER by scanning or using a certain URL. When I write any of the three URLs I just wrote above, the page loads but without that event selected.

What I want, is that when I write the first link, the event "Option1" is already clicked, loaded. And so on with each one. This is so that when someone writes/scans the QR code to open "Option2", for example, it will already be clicked for them, and they will already be able to see what's inside.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's perfectly fine if you want to remove personal details from the posts on this page, but it's also helpful for future users if the posts still make sense. Instead of just removing these URLs and names, I have therefore replaced them with more generic ones. I hope your still happy with the way this page is now? (I have made edits to both the question and the answer.)

Comment: Hey. Its fine, however, when I google my website. These two posts still appear. I know you modified the words but they still appear. Will this be temporal? Thanks

Comment: Google doesn't immediately get the updated version of every website. If you look at [google's cache of this page](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:NUAblpGKyZkJ:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62501307/auto-click-certain-javascript-even-on-certain-url-from-same-website+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=safari) you will see it was last crawled 3 days ago, so before the edit was made. Hopefully google will re-crawl this page soon, which should then solve the problem. But that can take several days or even weeks.

Comment: Okay. I'll wait a few weeks to see if it updates

Comment: Hey. So I am adding Google Ads to my website, and it is really being a bit of a problem that stackoverflow appears when people search for my business website. Is it possible that I can rewrite the post, with the modifications you made, and I can or someone answer with the previous answer I had gotten? Thanks

Comment: I understand your problem, but I don't actually think that would help. Even deleting this question and re-asking it (which I think you are suggesting) will only be noticed by google the next time it crawls the page, and sees the 404 error, by which time the problem would be solved anyway though. Google's cache still has the page "as it appeared on 25 Jun 2020" and that won't go away any quicker if you delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, you can detect if the current URL has a hash by reading `window.location.hash`. For example, if the url is `http://example.com/#id`, `window.location.hash` will return `"#id"`.

```
if (window.location.hash) {

    const hash = window.location.hash;

    // remove the "#" symbol from the string to get "id"
    const optionName = hash.substr(1);

    // now you can use optionName as id
    document.getElementById(optionName).style.display = "block";

    // for the link, you can use document.querySelector and select by href attribute
    const activeLink = document.querySelector('[href="' + hash + '"]');
    activeLink.className += ' active';
}
```

You might need to fine-tune this code, as I just glanced quickly at your site's scripts; but that's the idea of how to use `window.location.hash` for a case like this.

Comment: it worked man!!! you saved my project I'm extremely thankful